# (odoo)How can I upgrade my module in my module menu?

Tags: python, odoo

I am studying odoo now. But everytime I change my view with XML, I need to upgrade my module in app menu to refresh it.
Can I add a button in my own module to upgrade it?
I am using odoo 10.0. I tried to call the upgrade function in base module, but it doesn`t work.
Thank you!